# Footer Callback not being invoked

Tags: spring-batch

I have defined a footercallback , but the footer info is not being written to the File.
Here is the config and code. Am i missing something?
The afterstep gets called and the WriteCount is being written to the log but not to the file.
The job def:

```
<job id="sodfeed" job-repository="tplJobRepository" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <step id="readWriteBalances">
        <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="balancesReader" writer="balancesWriter"  commit-interval="100" >

        </chunk>    
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="tplBatchFooterCallback" />
                <listener ref="tplBatchFailureListener" />
            </listeners>


        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

public class FooterCallback extends StepExecutionListenerSupport implements FlatFileFooterCallback{

private StepExecution stepExecution;
public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.write("EOF" + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    System.out.println("**************************EOF" + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
}
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    ExitStatus returnStatus = stepExecution.getExitStatus();
  logger.info("Number of records written:"+stepExecution.getWriteCount());

    return returnStatus;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `tplBatchFooterCallback` correctly injected into your `FlatFileItemWriter`? Listeners and callback are used in a different way.

Lookup [official javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setFooterCallback%28org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileFooterCallback%29).